# Have some problems with my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

i have some problems with my script , i used JqueryUI tooltip but it doesn't work . 
Sample demo is given below.

http://jsfiddle.net/VFZL7/.

```
$(function() {
$("a[id*='product_wrap']").tooltip({
content: function(){return $(this).html().replace('150_','')},
track: true,
});
});
```

I want my tooltip indicates the image `petplusvn.com/files/sanpham/16/150.jpg` instead of `petplusvn.com/files/sanpham/16/150_1.jpg`.

Comment: I dont think that the problem is with javascript. Its with the image only. There is no such image in that path.]

Comment: It had image in HTML code , you can check in the link above , it only work when i delete the  `data-original` tag . But i dont want to change the html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to replace both URLs ( in src and data-original )

```
$(function() {

    $("a[id*='product_wrap']").tooltip({

        content: function(){
            var $html = $(this).html().replace(/150_/g, '');
            console.log('new HTML: '+$html);
            return $html;
        },
    track: true,

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Y8Au/